# Returning Void Pointer Truncates Value

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I'm having trouble returning a void pointer to another function in C.

HEADER FILE:

```
void *function2( void );
```

MAIN.C

```
#include "myHeader.h"

void function1 (){
    void *temp = NULL;
    temp = function2();
}
```

FUNCTION2.C

```
int a = 3;

void *function2(void){
    printf("Memory Address %p\n",&a );
    return (void *) &a; // value of &a is 0x100023444
}
```

However, the value of temp in function1() is 0x3444,instead of 0x100023444.

Does anyone know a solution for this, or if I am doing something wrong?

EDITED:
It seems, the header was added in the wrong place, leading to the problem described by AndreyT and Jonathan below, which seems to have fixed the truncation problem. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: `return &a` (the address of a local variable) is undefined behavior.

Comment: @YuHao: I don't think returning the address of a local variable is undefined behavior is it...?

Comment: I know that 'a' is a local variable and cannot be returned , the code above was just a quick way of demonstrating a subset of larger code. I apologize for the confusion, give me a sec to update the code for clarity

Comment: @Mehrdad: it is dubious, at best.  About the only thing you can do with it is print it, probably.  Any attempt to dereference is not guaranteed; it is not clear that you can even compare it, or print it.  That said, on most computers, printing is going to work, and comparisons will probably work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah I'm not sure if you can *do* anything with it per se, but merely returning it being undefined behavior just caught me by surprise so that's why I asked, ok.

Comment: This code produces no output. How do you know the value of `temp` is `0x1234`? Can you show us a complete program, with output, that exhibits the problem you're asking about? http://sscce.org/

Comment: "I'm having trouble returning a void pointer to another function in C" -- that's not defined behavior; pointers to functions aren't pointers to objects. But I don't see where you're using a pointer to a function.

Comment: It's not UB to merely return the address of a local variable, but it is UB if the calling function does anything at all with the return value.

Comment: @Merhdad " I don't think returning the address of a local variable is undefined behavior is it...?" -- Yes, it is undefined; pointers to objects are only valid during the lifetime of the object. A compiler that takes advantage of UB can do anything, including eliding the function.

Comment: @Mehrdad Oops, I take that back. According to section 6.2.4 of the C standard, the value of the pointer is indeterminate, and referring to the object is UB.

Comment: @JimBalter: Actually that's a slightly different point than I was making. The key thing here is that the pointer is perfectly valid when the `return` is executed, since at that point in time, the local variable is alive. So returning the pointer isn't a problem. It's only when you *use* the return value (e.g. read it, dereference it, etc.) that you start having to look into whether or not that's UB, but that's not what's happening here.

Comment: @Mehrdad Um, that's exactly what I said in my second comment. "that's not what's happening here" -- Well, no, because `a` isn't local.

Comment: @JimBalter: Sorry, that was confusing. When I said "here" I meant "in the scenario we're talking about" not "in the code above".

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, I know that. I really don't understand why you continued to post after my "Oops" that said virtually the same thing as your comment 19 minutes later, but life is full of mysteries, and I'm done here.

Comment: This is the correct syntax for declaring a pointer to a function:  void (*foo)(int);  then set the pointer like this:  foo = &my_int_func;  Then use the pointer like this: (*foo)( 2 ); or this: foo( 2 );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the revision to the question, I'm confident the problem is that you did not declare `function2()` before you used it.  Consequently, the compiler thinks it returns an `int`, not a `void *`.  It should also be complaining about the actual definition not matching the assumed declaration.

You should make sure your compiler options require you to define or declare a full prototype for each function before you use it.

Note that you should declare `void *function2(void);` because omitting the `void` in the parameter list means something quite different — it means the compiler is not told anything about what parameters it takes, not that it takes no parameters.  (This is a difference from C++.)

You still have problems because you're returning a pointer to a local variable.  You can probably print the pointer (though even that is not guaranteed by the standard), but you cannot reliably use it.

```
extern void *function2(void);

void function1(void)
{
    void *temp = function2();
    printf("Address: %p\n", temp);
}

void *function2(void)
{
    int a = 3;
    printf("Address: %p\n", &a);
    return &a; // value of &a is 0x1200001234
}
```

Or define `function2()` before defining `function1()`.

---

Note that it is crucial to include the header both where the function is defined (to make sure the definition is consistent with the header) and where the function is used (to make sure the use is consistent with the header).  As long as you do this, all will be well.

Answer (score 5):

Inside `function1` you are calling a yet-undeclared function `function2`. In classic C language (C89/90) this is allowed, but an undeclared function is assumed to return an `int`. Apparently, on your platform pointers are 64 bits wide and `int` is 32 bits wide. This is what causes a truncation of your 64-bit pointer value `0x1200001234` to 32 bits, giving you `0x1234`.

Formally, your code has undefined behavior, since after causing the compiler to assume that `function2` returns `int` you declared it as returning `void *`. Even C89/90 compilers usually issue a warning about this problem (and C99 compiler report an error). Did you ignore it?

Either move the entire definition of `function2` up and place it above `function1`

```
void *function2(void) {
    int a = 3;
    return &a;
}

void function1 (void){
    void *temp = NULL;
    temp = function2();
}
```

Or, alternatively, declare `function2` before calling it

```
void *function2(void);

void function1(void) {
    void *temp = NULL;
    temp = function2();
}

void *function2(void) {
    int a = 3;
    return &a;
}
```

You have to declare your functions before you call them (preferably with prototype).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is apart from truncation.

In function2() `a` is local variable. Here scope and lifetime od `a` limited to the function2. So returning the address to other function is illegal. It will cause undefined behavior. Please pay more attention to learn storage class in C